# Char Linked list with Buffer Ring in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, cygwin

I have a server and a client. The client can send request like ADD to list by entering ADD:Joe:2 it should add to list. Key = Joe Value =2.

I'm trying to ADD a key:value into a linked list that uses a buffer ring of max 5 elements. When the linked list reaches the max size of elements(5) and a new key:value is entered, the oldest element is overwritten with the new element.

Every time I adding it seems to add fine, but when the max size is reached and tries to delete the first KEY:VALUE it crashes.

Add to LIST:

```
 void push_item(struct item** Front,struct item** Rear,char *new_key,char *new_value,int newsockfd)
    {
        char buffer [50] = {0};

            struct item* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
            strcpy(new_node->value,new_value);
            strcpy(new_node->key,new_key);
            //new_node->next = NULL;
            if(p_size==5)
            {


                char *itemVal;
                char *itemKey;
                /* if queue is empty */
                if ( *Front == NULL )
                {
                    printf ( "List is empty");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (*Front == *Rear)
                    {
                        strcpy(itemVal,(*Front)->value);
                        strcpy(itemKey,(*Front)->key);
                        free(*Front);
                        *Front = NULL ;
                        *Rear = NULL ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //delete node
                        new_node = *Front;
                        strcpy(itemVal,new_node->value);
                        strcpy(itemKey,new_node->key);
                        *Front=(*Front)->next;
                        (*Rear)->next=*Front;
                        free(new_node);
                    }
                    printf("Node deleted Key: %s Value: %s",itemKey,itemVal);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                *Rear=new_node;
                (*Rear)->next=new_node;

                if(*Front==NULL)
                {
                    (*Front)=new_node;
                    p_size++;
                }
                else
                {
                    (*Rear)->next=new_node;
                    p_size++;
                    printf("Elements in List: %d\n",p_size);
                }

            }

            sprintf(buffer,"Added");
            int num_bytes = write(newsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
            if (num_bytes < 0) 
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Thread ERROR: write() failed\n");
            }
}
```

Server:

```
struct item *Front = NULL;
struct item *Rear = NULL;
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};

void* handle_client(void *socket)
{
    int newsockfd = (int)socket;
    pthread_t thread_id = pthread_self();

    printf("----------\nThread %lu using socket %x\n", (unsigned long)thread_id, newsockfd);

    /* Start communicating */
    int num_bytes = read(newsockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE-1);
    if (num_bytes < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Thread %lu ERROR: read() failed\n", (unsigned long)thread_id);
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("Thread %lu recieved request\n", (unsigned long)thread_id);

    if(strncmp(buffer,"ADD",3)==0)
    {
        char* key = buffer+4;
        int charIndex;
        char *new_value = strchr(buffer+4 , ':')+1;
        charIndex = (int)(new_value-buffer)-1;
        buffer[charIndex] = '\0';

        push_item(&Front,&Rear,key,new_value,newsockfd);

        printf("Value:%s Key:%s\n",new_value,key);
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Images of CMD :
[Left cmd is the client and the right one is the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDgm4.jpg)

The p_size represents the current number of elements in the linked list.
It Crashes  after it enters the if condition P_size == 5.

Comment: "It" crashes? Please elaborate.
Also it would be easy to single step through the code when max size is reached. Did you try that?

Comment: Linked list seldom means fixed size; ring buffer does mean fixed size. It's a puzzling combo.

Comment: @Peter when it enters the if  p_size==5 condition it just crashes, I used the cygwin debugger and it does not give me any information as seen in the image attached!

Answer (score 0):

When looking on the `push_item()` function for the problem located in case of `if(p_size==5)`, the error is when writing data of the node to be removed.

**Error 1** - temporary `itemVal` and `itemKey` are declared as `char *` but never allocated to an array.

```
// To do
strcpy(itemVal,(*Front)->value);
strcpy(itemKey,(*Front)->key);
// or
strcpy(itemVal,new_node->value);
strcpy(itemKey,new_node->key);
```

> Both `char *itemVal;` and `char *itemKey;` shall be allocated.

```
// Local variables (STR_SIZE has to be adjusted)
char itemVal[STR_SIZE+1];
char itemKey[STR_SIZE+1];
```

**Warning 1** - but solving that issue will reveal a malfunction in the Ring Buffer algorithm when using linked-list.

> In the `push_item()` function, the writing/push pointer `*Front` and
>   the reading/pop pointer `*Rear` are managed independently. When the
>   Ring Buffer is full (`if(p_size==5)`) the new item is deleted instead
>   of the oldest one.